# RLMCollection.h error while adding realm database in my swift project

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am creating todolist app but after pod installation of realm when I try to run the project these error is showing in my system. See this image:

[image]

I am not understanding whats the major problem.

I am getting `RLMCollection.h` error while adding realm database in my swift project.

try this link if you didnt find image

https://www.dropbox.com/s/wb01htr88iefd8r/IMG-20150513-WA0024.jpg?dl=0

Comment: Can you show us more ? Your `Podfile` for example. Did you opened the .xcworkspace after running `pod install` ?

Comment: Thanks for reply olivier.yes i have installed pod file and everything mentioned in realm website but dont know what is missing?all errors coming in RLMCollection.h file(approx 20).in this file languge is objective c

Comment: Could you also provide the version of CocoaPods, Realm and Xcode version you use?

Comment: xcode-6.4, pod-0.39.0 ,realm 1.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realm 1.0.1 does not support Xcode 6. The final version of Realm with Xcode 6 support was 0.102.1.

Comment: You can specify the version to use in your Podfile.